# Better way to store vendor unique ids

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq, message-queue

There are multiple vendors who provide me a bulk list of vendor id's that I need to assign for order placed for that vendor. These id's are not reusable. More like a unique id on the vendor side.

Currently I am storing it in RabbitMQ and for each insert I am getting one id specific to the vendor in the request and saving it. I sometimes get bulk requests where I need to get 100 ids at a time.

I am using Scala for development.

The other alternative that I can think of is a DB with used boolean column. With a stored proc returning records as requested.

What is the better approach. Any other suggestions are also welcome

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve exactly. What are you storing in Rabbit?

Comment: My vendor A sends me id's 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004 ... as his reference numbers. So when I book an order for that vendor, I need to assign his number. For eg. request (QuoteA) will respond with (ID1, VendorA, 10001) and another request will respond with (ID2, VendorA, 10002). Once they are used, I should not assign them back.

I am storing (10001, 10002, 10003 in my queue for Vendor A)

Comment: Are your vendors using RabbitMQ to send you ids?

Comment: When ever requested, they give csv files of 1000 id's each. I currently put them in Rabbit MQ. Want to know if RabbitMQ is the ideal solution?

Comment: I don't think RabbitMQ is a good solution. RabbitMQ is not a datastore and an healthy Rabbit is an empty one. Once an ID is used you should not assign them back. But can a vendor send twice the same id?